# Friend function with a definition - template or non-template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend

Suppose we have the following code:

```
template<class T> struct S;
template<class T> void operator++(S<T>);

template<class T> struct S {
    friend void operator++(S);
};

template<class T>
void operator++(S<T>) {}

int main() {
    S<int> s;
    ++s;
}
```

This will compile but won't link, because the `friend` declaration introduces a non-template `operator++`, that has never been defined.

[This FAQ answer](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends) reads (**bold** is mine):

> The solution is to **convince the compiler** while it is examining the class body proper that the **`operator++` function is itself a template**. There are several ways to do this;

The first way is to add `<>` into the friend declaration, and I'm not considering it here. The second is "to define the friend function within the class body":

```
template<class T> struct S {
    friend void operator++(S) { }
};
```

The quote suggests that `void operator++(S)` is now a function template and not a non-template function. Is it?

Comment: _"because the friend declaration introduces a non-template"_ It should not. `[temp.friend]/1.2` says otherwise: "For a friend function declaration that is not a template declaration: [...] if the name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching non-template function is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to that function". In your case, non non-template `operator++` is found.

Comment: @AndyG, can we say that providing a definition turns a declaration of a non-template function into a definition of a function template?

Comment: @YSC, do you suggest that the first code snippet should [link](https://godbolt.org/z/pf39s3)?

Comment: I know it doesn't, I just fail to understand why following the Standard.

Comment: At least `gcc` makes a clear statement (that agrees with the FAQ): https://godbolt.org/z/WWRB_w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a template, because its declaration is not that of a template (even though it appears inside a template declaration itself).

> **[temp.friend]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.friend#1) A friend of a class or class template can be a function template
>   or class template, a specialization of a function template or class
>   template, or a non-template function or class. **For a friend function
>   declaration that is not a template declaration**:
>
> - if the name of the friend is a qualified or unqualified template-id, the friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function
>     template, otherwise,
> - if the name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching non-template function is found in the specified class or namespace,
>     the friend declaration refers to that function, otherwise,
> - if the name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend
>     declaration refers to the deduced specialization of that function
>     template ([temp.deduct.decl]), otherwise,
> - **the name shall be an unqualified-id that declares (or redeclares) a non-template function**.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> class task;
> template<class T> task<T>* preempt(task<T>*);
>
> template<class T> class task {
>   friend void next_time();
>   friend void process(task<T>*);
>   friend task<T>* preempt<T>(task<T>*);
>   template<class C> friend int func(C);
>
>   friend class task<int>;
>   template<class P> friend class frd;
> };
> ```
>
> Here, each specialization of the task class template has the function
>   `next_­time` as a friend; **because `process` does not have explicit
>   template-arguments, each specialization of the task class template has
>   an appropriately typed function `process` as a friend, and this friend
>   is not a function template specialization**; because the friend
>   `preempt` has an explicit template-argument `T`, each specialization
>   of the `task` class template has the appropriate specialization of the
>   function template `preempt` as a friend; and each specialization of
>   the `task` class template has all specializations of the function
>   template `func` as friends. Similarly, each specialization of the
>   `task` class template has the class template specialization
>   `task<int>` as a friend, and has all specializations of the class
>   template `frd` as friends.  — end example ]

While examples are non-normative, the one in the quote clarifies the intent of the preceding normative text. Since the friend operator declaration is not a template declaration, the text in bold applies. It therefore declares a non-template function.

Comment: I don't understand why 1.3 doesn't apply _"if the name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to the deduced specialization of that function template"_

Comment: ho... it's an unqualified id :/ Well `friend void ::operator++(S);` doesn't link either.

Comment: @YSC I'm not even sure if `friend void ::operator++(S)` should compile. The standard clearly says that it either has to match a prior declaration or be unqualified.

Comment: @YSC - Rethinking, I suspect it doesn't link because only the declaration of the specialization is instantiated when deducing what `::operator++` refers to. I can't tell if it's a bug though. Unsure.

Comment: @YSC - To contrast, Clang does seem to implement 1.3 and links successfully https://godbolt.org/z/EpA9dr . So... GCC bug maybe?

Comment: Those narrow subtleties in Standard parsing are above my competency to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
template<class T> struct S {
    friend void operator++(S s) { }
};
```

`operator ++` is no longer template.

For more regular function (`operator` usage is a little different than function), it might allow deduction:

```
template<class T> struct S {
    S(T t);
    friend void foo(S lhs, S rhs) { }
};

template <typename T>
void bar(S<T> s, T t)
{
    foo(s, t);   // would not work if foo was template, would require foo<T>(s, t);
    foo(s, {t}); // would not work if foo was template, would require foo<T>(s, {t});
}
```