# Overload an operator of a struct inside a template struct

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

I have a template struct `Foo` that defines an inner struct `Bar`.

Now, I would like to overload the stream `operator <<` for this inner struct `Bar`, but the compiler seems to ignore my overload implementation:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘Foo<3>::Bar’)

My code is the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<int N>
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar  {};
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<int N>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const typename Foo<N>::Bar& x)
{
    return os;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo<3>::Bar x;

    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

I can't see the (maybe obvious) error.

**Question** Is it possible to overload an operator of an inner structure that belongs to a template class?

Comment: Dupe:[friend operator in nested class of templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832666/12002570)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar  {
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const Bar&) { return os;}
    };
};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo<3>::Bar x;

    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

---

In your code the `operator<<` is not actually wrong. Its just impossible to deduce `N` from `Foo<N>::Bar`. You can only call it by making `N` explicit:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo<3>::Bar x;
    operator<<<3>(std::cout,x);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hd9aM3xGz).

---

The reason is that `Foo<N>::Bar` is a non deduced context. See [What is a non-deduced context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-non-deduced-context) for more details. In a nutshell, the reason why this does not work is that there is no 1:1 relation between `Foo<N>::Bar` and `N`. Consider you add a specialization:

```
template <> struct Foo<42> {
      using Bar = Foo<3>::Bar;
};
```

Now `Foo<42>::Bar` and `Foo<3>::Bar` refer to exactly the same type. This

```
Foo<3>::Bar x;
std::cout << x;
```

and this

```
Foo<42>::Bar x;
std::cout << x;
```

would have to deduce different values for `N` but in both examples `x` is of exactly the same type.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer; I have learnt something new today in C++ and I guess I have many days like this in front of me !

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?
With template classes it is usually easier to declare friend overloads within the template (demo here: https://onlinegdb.com/NqTLD6_tU)

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar
    { 
        int x{N};
    };
    
    // friend if you need access to a private member
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo<N>::Bar& bar)
    {
        os << bar.x;
        return os;
    }

private:
    Bar b; 
};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo<3>::Bar x;
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that since it's now inside the definition of `Foo`, you can simplify the parameter declaration for the operator a bit, to just `const Bar &` rather than `const Foo<N>::Bar &`. https://godbolt.org/z/33xno8qMb

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am quite sure I tried something similar, but not similar enough to make it compile !